# Must I abandon legacy ERD diagrams in Visio 2013?

Tags: ms-office, visio

I have several ERD diagrams that I have been maintaining in Visio for several versions.  They are not *real* big but would represent more effort than I want to invest if I had to recreate them from scratch.  The potential of making typos is pretty high.

Visio 2013 doesn't support editing these documents.  Is there a way I can convert the Visio 2010 version of the ERD to something that Visio 2013 will allow me to edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the ERD Visio addon was discontinued in Visio 2013. Although some basic database shapes and templates are still there, most of the functionality you had in previous versions of Visio is gone.

I am afraid you have to stick with Visio 2010.